# JQuery show() function not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-effects

I have the following JQuery code:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
        var retrievedList = [ {
            "id" : "one",
            "content" : "toto"
        }, {
            "id" : "two",
            "content" : "titi"
        }, {
            "id" : "three",
            "content" : "tutu"
        } ];
        $("#clickMe").click(function(evt){
            $.each(retrievedList, function(i, v) {
                if(!$('div#list> span#' + v.id).length) {
                    $('<span />').prop('id', v.id).text(v.content).appendTo('#list').show(8000);
                }
            });
            return false;
        });
    });
```

I am surprised to notice that the show function call does not work on the `span` that I create.

Can anyone tell me why and how to remedy this problem?

EDIT: Here is the html:

```
<div id="list">
<span id="one">toto</span> <span id="two">titi</span>
</div>
<a href="" id="clickMe">clickMe</a>
```

Comment: It's not the `show` and that code is a mess. know that id is enough to select with.

Comment: Hi gdoron: what do you mean by: "know that id is enough to select with." ?

Comment: But what's the problem? see [THIS](http://jsfiddle.net/p5Ke9/)

Comment: Thanks for the link Alex. The `span`  is appended but the effect does not work. Does it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of this:

```
$('<span />').prop('id', v.id).text(v.content).appendTo('#list').show(8000);
```

Try using this:

```
var span = $('<span />').prop('id', v.id).text(v.content).css('display', 'none');
$('#list').append(span);
$('#'+v.id).show(8000);
```

Comment: Have you checked to see if the `span` is actually appended?

Comment: I've updated the answer. If the `span` is indeed appended, using an id selector should work

Comment: Updated the answer again. The `span` needs to be hidden for the show effect to work. You can do it with `hide` or with css `display: none`.

Comment: Thanks Spider. It's a bit of a hack but it does work. Funny we have to hide it in order to show it afterwards...

Comment: Actually that's how it should work. If the element was already visible when the `show` method was called then it would flicker because the `show method would need to hide it before it can animate it.

Comment: I tried with `display: none` as follows: `var span = $('<span />').prop('id', v.id).text(v.content).css("display: none");
         $('#list').append(span);
         $('#'+v.id).show(8000);` and it does not work.

Comment: It should be `css('display', 'none')`. See updated answer. http://api.jquery.com/css/

Comment: With `display: none` I was reffering to add this rule to a css stylesheet like so `#list span { display: none; }`